# Programmatically choose template to include?

Tags: python, django, templates

So I've got huge pile of content I'd like to serve, and I'd like to be able to pass a parameter in the context that specifies which template file to include. The only alternative I can think of is to have a template for each piece of content I've got, which is messy, or read the content from a file in the view and pass it into the template as a context parameter, which I'd rather not do.

What's the "proper" way to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a (context) variable to include, and it will look at the value of that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Thus:

```
{% include "foo.html" %}
```

is the same as:

```
{# foo is "foo.html", set in view function #}
{% include foo %}
```